# Horizontal Scrolling of divs not working as expected

Tags: html, css

I've made a jsfiddle to demo my issue:  [here it is along with the css](http://jsfiddle.net/rbarkas/PvY5Z/)

```
<div -d=wrapper">
<div id="header">Hello, I'm the header</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="content-left" >Some text in left</div>
    <div id="content-right">Some text in right</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

What I want is for the divs content-left and content-right to get narrower and sprout scroll bars as the window is made narrower in the x axis.

What it does is once there's not enough room for both divs, it stacks content-right under content-left instead of narrowing them.  I'd prefer for the scroll bars to appear only when required.

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly set `width` for #content otherwise it will try to be clever and wrap the elements.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WrZ3x/)

```
#content {width:300px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PvY5Z/4/)**

Set a `max-width` if you need to on the `#content`... Then give each column a 50% width.

```
#content{
max-width: 300px;
}

#content-left{
width: 50%;
}

#content-right{
width: 50%;
}
```